# scroll area data is centre aligned want to change it to left aligned

Tags: c++, qt

```
ui->setupUi(this);

QWidget *win = new QWidget();
QVBoxLayout* lay = new QVBoxLayout(win);
lay->setAlignment(Qt::AlignTop | Qt::AlignLeft);

QPushButton *botton = new QPushButton(cmd);
lay->addWidget(botton);


ui->scrollAreaWidgetContents->setLayout(lay);
```

the data in the scroll area is center aligned and want to change this to left alignment
from past few days i am trying to make the data to be left aligned but its not changing 
can anyone help me in this regard

Comment: You want to align the button to the left ?

Answer (score 0):

Add spacer item to the right side into horizontal layout.

```
  QHBoxLayout * poHLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
  QPushButton * button = new QPushButton(cmd);

  // Spacer item
  QWidget * poSpacerItem = new QWidget(this);

  poSpacerItem->setSizePolicy(
                    QSizePolicy::Minimum,QSizePolicy::Maximum);

  // Add your button to the left side. (will align button to left)
  poHLayout->addWidget(button);      
  // Add spacer item
  poHLayout->addWidget(poSpacerItem);


  ui->scrollAreaWidgetContents->setLayout(poHLayout);
```

Comment: @sravan: do you need any more help with this question?